# Build Apache module in C

Tags: apache2, mysql, modules

I've a problem in building a Apache c module.
For compiling the module, i use the statement:

```
sudo apxs2 -I/usr/include/mysql -i -a -c mod_aledav.c
```

and the module seems to be compiled correctly, but when i try to restart Apache, the output is:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 239 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/aledav.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_aledav.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_aledav.so: undefined symbol: mysql_errno
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved.
I've added a command in the statement line:

```
$(mysql_config --libs)
```

so the new statement is

```
apxs2 -I/usr/include/mysql -i -a -c $(mysql_config --libs) mod_aledav.c
```

After restarting the apache2 service, the module is loaded.

From the 
[mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html)

so a new statement is

```
sudo apxs2 -I/usr/include/mysql -i -a -c -lmysqlclient -lz  mod_aledav.c
```